# Activity OnConfigurationChange is not being called

Tags: android, android-activity, onconfigurationchanged

My Activity onConfigurationChanged is not called at all. I have updated my SDK API to Marshmallow ;

In my code overwrite "onConfigurationChanged":

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.d(HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName() , "called"); // not called
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d(HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "called"); // not called
```

In my Android Manifest I declared:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
```

And i'm calling for changing language :

```
public void changeLocale(Locale locale) {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale(locale.toString().toLowerCase());
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

Does anyone know what changed or what I am doing wrong/missed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onConfigurationChanged()` will only be called if the user changes the Locale (language) setting of the phone. Just calling `Resources.updateConfiguration()` does not trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the manifest under your activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: if this has answered your question please mark it correct